# Spring JPA repository update multiple entities with a single query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

At the moment I have the following code which iterates a list of parameter entities and updates each of their names in the database:

```java
public class test {

    @Autowired
    private ParameterJpaRepository parameterJpaRepository;

    public updateParameters(List<Parameter> parameters) {
       for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
           parameterJpaRepository.setNameById(parameter.getId(), parameter.getName());
       }
    }
}
```

```java
public interface ParameterJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Parameter, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Parameter p SET p.name = :name WHERE p.id = :id")
    void setNameById(@Param("id") long id, @Param("name") String name);
}
```

Obviously, this results in **N** queries:

```sql
Hibernate: update parameter set name=? where id=?
Hibernate: update parameter set name=? where id=?
Hibernate: update parameter set name=? where id=?
Hibernate: update parameter set name=? where id=?
```

I would like to combine then into a single query equivalent to this attempt:

```java
public interface ParameterJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Parameter, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Parameter p SET p.name = (:names) WHERE p.id = (:ids)")
    void setNameById(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids, @Param("names") List<String> names);
}
```

Which should yield something like:

```sql
Hibernate: UPDATE parameter
           SET name = (case when id = ? then ?
                            when id = ? then ?
                            when id = ? then ?
                            when id = ? then ?
                       end)
           WHERE id in (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE Parameter p SET p.name = (CASE " +
               "WHEN p.id IN (:ids) THEN (CASE " +
               "WHEN p.id = :ids[0] THEN :names[0] " +
               "WHEN p.id = :ids[1] THEN :names[1] " +
               "WHEN p.id = :ids[2] THEN :names[2] " +
               // ...
               "ELSE p.name " +
               "END) " +
               "ELSE p.name " +
               "END) " +
               "WHERE p.id IN (:ids)", nativeQuery = true)
void setNameById(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids, @Param("names") List<String> names);
```

This is a bad approach. Don't try to do that.

It's very bad for large lists, since the query will become very long and very difficult to maintain.
It does not work if the ids and names lists are not in the same order.
If you need to update a big number of rows, or if the order of the ids and names lists is not fixed, you might want to consider using a different approach, such as executing a separate update statement for each row or using a temporary table .

Answer (score 3):

(Un)fortunately, `spring-data-jpa` functionality is not so flexible as you would like to see, however it does allow to create [Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and thus you may write any update query you want, some examples:

- https://thorben-janssen.com/composite-repositories-spring-data-jpa/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/custom-spring-data-repository/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories

by the way, you need to keep in mind that in general that is not a good idea to update hibernate entities via direct update, the reasoning is following:

- it is not cache friendly - if you are using second level cache, hibernate needs to completely cleanup those cache, cause it has no chance to get know what entities have been updated
- if you are using auditing solution like [envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/), direct update bypasses that solution

so, sometimes it is much better to enable batch updates and write something like:

```java
@Transactional
default void setNameById(List<Long> ids, List<String> names) {
    Map<Long, Parameter> data = StreamSupport.stream(findAllById(ids).spliterator(), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Customer::getId,
                    Function.identity()
            ));
    
    for (int i = 0, n = ids.size(); i < n; i++) {
        Parameter parameter = data.get(ids.get(i));
        if (parameter != null) {
            parameter.setName(names.get(i));
        }
    }

    saveAll(data.values());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is old but I will share it anyway.

Please check [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77038282/calling-stored-procedure-with-typed-parameter-from-java-spring-boot-using-proce?noredirect=1#comment135979174_77038282) and my answer after I fought with this issue for long time.

It is using hibernate 6.

The idea behind it is to create a custom type in the DB having (in your case) long and string - Id, name.

Create a UserType to allow hibernate convert your type into db type.

Create a stored procedure to update your data in a single statement.

```
-- db script

CREATE TYPE YourCustomType AS (
    id long,
    name varchar(100)
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateBulk(yourData YourCustomType[])  AS $$
BEGIN
   UPDATE Parameter as db
   SET db.name = val.name 
   FROM (SELECT * from UNNEST(yourArrayOfData)) as val
   WHERE db.id = val.id
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

after adding the object in java as in my post + creating a `UserType` + contributing the type + then add this to the repo

```
@Procedure(value= "update_bulk")
void updateBulk(Yourtype[] data);
```

Have fun..