# Calling stored procedure with typed parameter from java spring boot using @Procedure

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, stored-procedures

I've developed a stored procedure to do some task in the DB which gets a custom type parameter.

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS custom_type CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE custom_type AS (
    field1 integer,
    field2 integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc(param1 custom_type) AS $$
BEGIN
    -- DO NOTHING FOR NOW
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

in my java code I've created this custom type as a class and added connection to the procedure in my repository as followed..

```
@Data
public class CustomType {
    int field1;
    int field2;
    public CustomType(Integer field1, Integer field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

```
public interface MyRepo extends RdbFilterQueryRepository<MyEntity> {

   @Procedure(value = "my_proc")
   void myProc(@Param("param1") CustomType myParam1);

}
```

When I call the procedure I get this error:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine the bindable type for procedure parameter: null`

I've tried many ways but nothing worked out. I've changed the custom type to a simple integer and it works.. I understand that it is connected to the parameter type and binding between the type in the DB to my class type. But I don't find a way to do it.
What am I missing?

---UPDATE---

I've managed to make it work with a simple custom type (containing single field), by implementing `UserType<T>` as a type converter, and registering it by another component implementation for  `TypeContributor`.

In our case the custom type has more than one field. So I've tried to implement the type converter `CompositeUserType<T>` but sadly I don't manage to register it, because the `TypeContributor` register function gets only `UserType<T>`.

I've created a ticket in hibernate for it. They suggested a workaround using `@CompositeTypeRegistration` but it does not work as well..

Comment: Hello, have you had any luck with this. I am currently having the same issue

Comment: Not really..  updated my Question  - Check it out if it help your case. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75823682/how-do-i-register-a-compositeusertype-in-hibernate-6) as well

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found a way to make it work. It is not optimal but it works.

Our java type - equivalent to our postgres type `custom_type` (check out DB declaration at my post)

```
public record MyType(int field1, int field2) {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + field1 + "," + field2 + ")";
        }
    }
```

Declaring the converter type

```
class MyUserType implements UserType<MyType> {
    ...

    public static final MyUserType INSTANCE = new MyUserType();


    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, MyType value, int index, 
    SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws SQLException {
        st.setString(index, value.toString());
    }

    ...
}
```

Registering our custom type

```
public class MyUserTypesContributor implements TypeContributor {

    public MyUserTypesContributor () {
    }

    @Override
    public void contribute(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        typeContributions.contributeType(MyUserType.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

create the file
`./resources/META-INF.services/org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor`
content of the file will be the full package of this type contributor

```
com......hibernate.types.MyUserTypesContributor
```

This way our types contributor will be loaded by hibernate and our type will be registered

In the repository

```
public interface MyRepository extends RdbFilterQueryRepository<...> {
    ...

    @Procedure("my_procedure")
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    void myProc(@Param("param1")  MyType val);
     
    ...
}
```

and what left to do is to call our procedure

```
myRepo.myProc(new MyType(123,345));
```